# Flask + gunicorn + nginx + google linux debian ssh setup 500 internal server error

Tags: python, nginx, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

After deploying the app with the config above, I get 500 internal server error, but only on my register, login and login-with google pages, as well as post requests.

Here's what I tried:

1. Checked for nginx error logs: Nothing there, except some errors from hours ago.
2. Checked for Gunicorn error logs: Same thing, nothing new except some errors i know i solved.
3. Tried to set debug=True in flask app, but I get no output when the app is deployed.
4. Tried it in local development, works all well.

###### `/etc/nginx/sites-available/ponder.conf`

```nginxconf
server{
    server_name ponder.ink www.ponder.ink;

    location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ponder_contactus/Ponderproject/app/peak.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ponder.ink/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ponder.ink/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server{
    if ($host = www.ponder.ink) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = ponder.ink) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name ponder.ink www.ponder.ink;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

###### `/etc/systemd/system/run.service`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Ponder Flask app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ponder_contactus/Ponderproject/app
Environment="PATH=/home/ponder_contactus/Ponderproject/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ponder_contactus/Ponderproject/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:peak.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Your problem is with the Python Flask application. Most likely your app is throwing an exception that your code is not managing. Test your app locally before deploying to the cloud.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: @JohnHanley , I already tested it in my local deployment. I wrote it in the post above. I've been making this for months now and register and log-in hasn't been throwing errors in a long time.

Comment: Based on your answer, you did not successfully test it locally.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! After running sudo systemctl status run.service (run is name of my service file ) right after the 500, you can check it and debug. Even though it works on the local server, it still crashes on the https.

Edit: While running the command, I noticed an error that was involving csrf protection and had needed a key.The key was stored inside an .env file and it ran locally. To fix, I just changed it from load_dotenv(flask_secret_key) to os.urandom(24)

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Show what you changed and not just state a command that you ran. Add more context and details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).